# Webdriver Selenium Won't Work - Python/Linux

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've installed everything to the tee, but it just won't work. Every time I try the example on the site http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html

I get
:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys ImportError: cannot import name Keys

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now, does anyone have any advice?

Comment: My guess is that everything is *not* installed properly.  Can you do `import selenium` without getting an error?  If yes, maybe try a re-install, and maybe use a virtual environment.  If no, then maybe selenium is installed somewhere outside your PATH.

Comment: Interesting how the error is pointing to line 2, yet in the sample code on the site it imports Keys on line 3.